# SSH through HTTP proxy with Socat got CreateProcessW failed error:2 posix_spawnp: No such file or directory

Tags: ssh, proxy, socat

I'm trying to establish an SSH connection to my remote host at x.x.x.x from a **Windows** machine.
I'm behind an HTTP proxy which filters only HTTP(S) packages.

The first thing I did was to bind my remote host SSH server to port 443.

If I try to make a simple `ssh -p 443 x.x.x.x` the connections goes in timeout because it must pass through the HTTP proxy (let's say y.y.y.y)

I cannot use nc/ncat on this pc because they are noticed as malicious, however I'm allowed to use **socat**.

I already search on the internet and I found this solution:
`ssh -o ProxyCommand='socat - "PROXY:%h:%p|tcp:y.y.y.y:8080"' x.x.x.x`

The problem is I get the error:
`CreateProcessW failed error:2  posix_spawnp: No such file or directory`

I already tried by giving socat the absolute path and the extension as well but I got the same error:
`ssh -o ProxyCommand='C:/Users/MyUser/Download/socat/socat.exe - "PROXY:%h:%p|tcp:y.y.y.y:8080"' x.x.x.x`

Where does the issue come from?

Comment: You should mention, that this error happens on a windows system. Did you tried backslashes? `ssh -o ProxyCommand='C:\Users\...` You should increase verbosity by `ssh -vvv -o ...`

Comment: Probably it's not possible to solve your problem with socat, it depends on the proxy / firewall. If the firewall use deep packet inspection, you need an SSL layer over your ssh data. That could be solved with openssl. Btw. Do you can use docker on that PC?

Comment: By adding the -vvv, I was been able to notice that the OS was loogin for the program called 'socat
I thus changed the single quote with double ones to solve the problem!